# How to get data from database week wise between two given dates?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, group-by

I have a SQL database where i saved data of all dates in table. What i want is, If given any two dates, i want all the data between those two dates in weekly format where week starts on Monday. if given date starts with Thursday for example, so data from Thursday to sunday should be displayed as a week data.

I give you one example. If i choose start date 08-01-2020 and end date 08-03-2020. Now this is two months gap and there are probably 30 days. I want data of those 30 days, but week wise from Monday to Sunday. But here given start date is on Wednesday, so the that weeks data would start from wednesday and end on sunday.

Suppose i have this table

```
1   2020-03-15  VDIZHO
2   2020-03-14  MV2XSS
3   2020-03-13  U6Y5OT
4   2020-03-12  C7V6ZJ
5   2020-03-11  LDQ44E
6   2020-03-10  9KY4Z3
7   2020-03-09  NWS6LU
8   2020-03-08  WBD0OB
9   2020-03-07  DMQ7WX
10  2020-03-06  BME2UO
11  2020-03-05  SOXW67
12  2020-03-04  MKJ4B3
13  2020-03-03  VDN9Z3
14  2020-03-02  130VGA
15  2020-03-01  7DDUQC
16  2020-02-29  DNUDGD
17  2020-02-28  CCC7H0
18  2020-02-27  UPO42A
19  2020-02-26  L9QEU6
20  2020-02-25  608W1F
21  2020-02-24  OE24W1
22  2020-02-23  Z8XW75
23  2020-02-22  43G5A7
24  2020-02-21  NXOZRV
25  2020-02-20  ZXRVD7
26  2020-02-19  CGP9E9
27  2020-02-18  12U1L2
28  2020-02-17  MOUTYM
29  2020-02-16  8H50CS
30  2020-02-15  FIREGUN
```

If choose date from 2020-02-15 to 2020-03-15, i want data like....

Week 1 : (Week starts from Monday to Sunday, here week started on saturday and ended on Sunday)

```
29  2020-02-16  8H50CS
30  2020-02-15  FIREGUN
```

Week 2 : (From Monday to Sunday)

```
22  2020-02-23  Z8XW75
23  2020-02-22  43G5A7
24  2020-02-21  NXOZRV
25  2020-02-20  ZXRVD7
26  2020-02-19  CGP9E9
27  2020-02-18  12U1L2
28  2020-02-17  MOUTYM
```

Week 3 :

```
15  2020-03-01  7DDUQC
16  2020-02-29  DNUDGD
17  2020-02-28  CCC7H0
18  2020-02-27  UPO42A
19  2020-02-26  L9QEU6
20  2020-02-25  608W1F
21  2020-02-24  OE24W1
```

and so on. Hope you got my point.

Comment: ```...
FROM sourcetable
WHERE `date` BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(`date`, 3)
...```

Comment: Do you want a query that works for both MySQL and SQL-server? Date handling is very different between vendors, I don't think there is a solution that works for both.

Comment: Solution that akina gave me is different what i wanted. I want data of each day in every week . Let me edit question for more info.

Comment: *If choose date from 2020-02-15 to 2020-03-15, i want data like....* Your "like" is about nothing. Show direct output which you want to receive using shown source data and condition - as one solid recordset.

Comment: i want data from start date till end date. Grouped by week. Now if given start date and end date has 12 weeks, i want data of each day in week.  i want all data between two dates, i just want to show it in clusters of week where each cluster has all 7 days.

Comment: Please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML, perhaps using a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3e9aec0dfb316760c09bb38e9aea1027).

Comment: *i want data from start date till end date. Grouped by week.* Show how it must look like in SOLID RECORDSET. *i just want to show it in clusters of week where each cluster has all 7 days.* This is your client problem - how to format the data received from the SQL server. Not SQL server task.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0xPXePmY8AdSjrq5Vl4hsXP5RmdWLnf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the HTML file where i want to show data. This has currently only one week table. But these table will increase as our weeks increases.Each table has data of one week and in this table, we have to put data of all the weeks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11YApDF5qLtgr8iR9M5v-qryPkjGvCaWD/view?usp=sharing        Here is the link of sheet where we have two weeks of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #temp(id int,dates date,col1 varchar(30))
insert into #temp 
values
 (1   ,'2020-03-15',' VDIZHO')
,(2   ,'2020-03-14',' MV2XSS')
,(3   ,'2020-03-13',' U6Y5OT')
,(4   ,'2020-03-12',' C7V6ZJ')
,(5   ,'2020-03-11',' LDQ44E')
,(6   ,'2020-03-10',' 9KY4Z3')
,(7   ,'2020-03-09',' NWS6LU')
,(8   ,'2020-03-08',' WBD0OB')
,(9   ,'2020-03-07',' DMQ7WX')
,(10  ,'2020-03-06',' BME2UO')
,(11  ,'2020-03-05',' SOXW67')
,(12  ,'2020-03-04',' MKJ4B3')
,(13  ,'2020-03-03',' VDN9Z3')
,(14  ,'2020-03-02',' 130VGA')
,(15  ,'2020-03-01',' 7DDUQC')
,(16  ,'2020-02-29',' DNUDGD')
,(17  ,'2020-02-28',' CCC7H0')
,(18  ,'2020-02-27',' UPO42A')
,(19  ,'2020-02-26',' L9QEU6')
,(20  ,'2020-02-25',' 608W1F')
,(21  ,'2020-02-24',' OE24W1')
,(22  ,'2020-02-23',' Z8XW75')
,(23  ,'2020-02-22',' 43G5A7')
,(24  ,'2020-02-21',' NXOZRV')
,(25  ,'2020-02-20',' ZXRVD7')
,(26  ,'2020-02-19',' CGP9E9')
,(27  ,'2020-02-18',' 12U1L2')
,(28  ,'2020-02-17',' MOUTYM')
,(29  ,'2020-02-16',' 8H50CS')
,(30  ,'2020-02-15',' FIREGU')

declare @SysDefault int= @@DATEFIRST -- first get ur system default datedifrt

set datefirst 1 -- tune here
;With CTE as
(
select *,DATEPART(wk,dates)weeknum 

from #temp
)
select * from CTE

set datefirst @SysDefault  -- after getting desire result reset 

drop table #temp
```

New Edit :,

Sample data containing Jan 1,

```
create table #temp(id int,dates date,col1 varchar(30))
insert into #temp 
values
 (1   ,'2020-01-15',' VDIZHO')
,(2   ,'2020-01-14',' MV2XSS')
,(3   ,'2020-01-13',' U6Y5OT')
,(4   ,'2020-01-12',' C7V6ZJ')
,(5   ,'2020-01-11',' LDQ44E')
,(6   ,'2020-01-10',' 9KY4Z3')
,(7   ,'2020-01-09',' NWS6LU')
,(8   ,'2020-01-08',' WBD0OB')
,(9   ,'2020-01-07',' DMQ7WX')
,(10  ,'2020-01-06',' BME2UO')
,(11  ,'2020-01-05',' SOXW67')
,(12  ,'2020-01-04',' MKJ4B3')
,(13  ,'2020-01-03',' VDN9Z3')
,(14  ,'2020-01-02',' 130VGA')
,(15  ,'2020-01-01',' 7DDUQC')
,(16  ,'2020-02-29',' DNUDGD')
,(17  ,'2020-02-28',' CCC7H0')
,(18  ,'2020-02-27',' UPO42A')
,(19  ,'2020-02-26',' L9QEU6')
,(20  ,'2020-02-25',' 608W1F')
,(21  ,'2020-02-24',' OE24W1')
,(22  ,'2020-02-23',' Z8XW75')
,(23  ,'2020-02-22',' 43G5A7')
,(24  ,'2020-02-21',' NXOZRV')
,(25  ,'2020-02-20',' ZXRVD7')
,(26  ,'2020-02-19',' CGP9E9')
,(27  ,'2020-02-18',' 12U1L2')
,(28  ,'2020-02-17',' MOUTYM')
,(29  ,'2020-02-16',' 8H50CS')
,(30  ,'2020-02-15',' FIREGU')
```

Comment: Will that work correctly for a week spanning Jan 1?

Comment: @RickJames, Don't know what exactly you mean ? Check my New Edit.Are you talking abt that kind of sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

Take the day from some base (`TO_DAYS()`), add a fudge factor (`5` for Monday) to get to the date start you desire.  Then divide by 7 (days per week), etc.  Now you have the `week_num` that you can `GROUP BY`.

For simplicity, I used MariaDB's "sequence table" to easily generate dates.  But that is not relevant to the question.

I specifically picked a range across the end-of-year because "week number" is messy when trying to use the standard functions.

```
SELECT  dy day_num,
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(dy), "%a %Y-%m-%d") the_date, 
        7 * FLOOR((dy + 5) / 7)  AS week_num,
        FROM_DAYS(7 * FLOOR((dy + 5) / 7) - 5) wk_start
    FROM ( SELECT TO_DAYS('2019-12-20') + seq AS dy
               FROM seq_0_to_21 ) AS x;

+---------+----------------+----------+------------+
| day_num | the_date       | week_num | wk_start   |
+---------+----------------+----------+------------+
|  737778 | Fri 2019-12-20 |   737779 | 2019-12-16 |
|  737779 | Sat 2019-12-21 |   737779 | 2019-12-16 |
|  737780 | Sun 2019-12-22 |   737779 | 2019-12-16 |
|  737781 | Mon 2019-12-23 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737782 | Tue 2019-12-24 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737783 | Wed 2019-12-25 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737784 | Thu 2019-12-26 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737785 | Fri 2019-12-27 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737786 | Sat 2019-12-28 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737787 | Sun 2019-12-29 |   737786 | 2019-12-23 |
|  737788 | Mon 2019-12-30 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737789 | Tue 2019-12-31 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737790 | Wed 2020-01-01 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737791 | Thu 2020-01-02 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737792 | Fri 2020-01-03 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737793 | Sat 2020-01-04 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737794 | Sun 2020-01-05 |   737793 | 2019-12-30 |
|  737795 | Mon 2020-01-06 |   737800 | 2020-01-06 |
|  737796 | Tue 2020-01-07 |   737800 | 2020-01-06 |
|  737797 | Wed 2020-01-08 |   737800 | 2020-01-06 |
|  737798 | Thu 2020-01-09 |   737800 | 2020-01-06 |
|  737799 | Fri 2020-01-10 |   737800 | 2020-01-06 |
+---------+----------------+----------+------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```